# Union all geometry in a SQL Server table like GeomUnion in Postgres

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, spatial

Just to clarify up-front: I'm talking about unioning geometry, not the SQL keyword `UNION`.

I'm trying to move some spatial data from Postgres with PostGIS to SQL Server 2008. It was fine until I saw a statement like this:

```
SELECT GeomUnion(the_geom) FROM some_table
```

This unions all geometry in that column and return it as one result (similar to how `COUNT` works). As far I know, SQL Server only has the `STUnion` function, which unions one geometry with another. Is there any way to do something similar to the Postgres way?

If it helps, the `STUnion` function works like this:

```
SELECT first_geometry_column.STUnion(second_geometry_column) FROM some_table
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't worked with spatial data :). 
Can you not use Common table expression and STUnion in combination to get the desired GeomUnion functionality ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way I ended up doing this is with variables:

```
DECLARE @Shape GEOMETRY
SET @Shape = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY', @MySrid)

SELECT @Shape = @Shape.STUnion(Shape)
  FROM MyShapeTable
```

It's not as nice, but it works.

Comment: And it gets *really* expensive for more than a handful of geometries.

Answer (score 12):

Is the UnionAggregate function SQL2012 only?

```
SELECT geography::UnionAggregate( geometry ) FROM some_table
```

Hmm guess so.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929095.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the info. Saved a lot of time! FYI: For geometry data it is geometry::UnionAggregate(geometry).

Comment: This is absolutely the answer to the original question, for SQL 2012 and above.

Answer (score 5):

Your best option is to create a CLR function to support the aggregate. There are a couple of existing solutions:

- [Sql spatial tools](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/)
- [Spatail aggregate](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2007/12/sql-server-2008-geometry-stunion.html)

Comment: You're correct - that's the best option for SQL 2008 but it's very slow and causes small geometry errors.  Thankfully, SQL2012 is lightning fast and doesn't have geometry issues. MS have stated that they are not going to fix the geometry issues in SQL2008.