# How to combine multiple LineString rows into a single row collection

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, geospatial, spatial

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and the `Geometry` datatype to store a list of UK a roads, which I've imported from the [Ordanance Survey STRATEGI](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/strategi/) data set.

Each road is split into multiple rows, which each contain a single line *(A `Linestring` made up of one segment)*. For instance the A369 is made up of 18 seperate lines, as shown in the image below:

[image: Screen capture of current linestrings]

What I'd like to do it collect all the seperate rows containing portions of a road and create a new row which holds all the combined individual lines as one linestring.

In other words running the code `SELECT * FROM Structure WHERE Name = 'A369'` would return only one row, but still drawn the road seen in the image above.

Comment: There is a discussion about this here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293190/union-all-geometry-in-a-sql-server-table-like-geomunion-in-postgres

Comment: Been looking for this too but I can't see any other (good) way that adding a CLR function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use .STUnion

```
BEGIN
-- create a test table
DECLARE @test TABLE(seg GEOMETRY);
INSERT INTO @test VALUES(geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (0 0, 50 100)', 0))
INSERT INTO @test VALUES(geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (50 100, 100 200)', 0))
INSERT INTO @test VALUES(geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (100 200, 150 300)', 0))
--SELECT seg.STAsText() FROM @test
DECLARE @geom GEOMETRY
SELECT @geom = (SELECT TOP 1 seg FROM @test)
-- union all the linestring points
SELECT @geom = @geom.STUnion([seg]) FROM @test
-- do what you want with the results
SELECT @geom
print(@geom.STAsText())
END
```

Answer (score 3):

In SQL 2012 you can use UnionAggregate

```
SELECT geometry::UnionAggregate(shape) FROM Table
```

or if you have a geography column

```
SELECT geography ::UnionAggregate(shape) FROM Table
```