# Calculating the outer boundary of several Geometry objects in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, geospatial, spatial, spatial-query

I have lots of `Polygons` of datatype `Geometry` in SQL Server 2008. The image below shows how a select of all these Geometrys looks visualized.

[image: Lots of Geometrys]

What I need to do is create a Polygon which represents the outer boundary of all these polygons. So I used the [response given to a previous spatial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154672/how-to-combine-multiple-linestring-rows-into-a-single-row-collection) I asked to create the following code:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE(geom GEOMETRY);

INSERT INTO @test SELECT geom FROM ForceBoundary

DECLARE @geom GEOMETRY
SELECT @geom = (SELECT TOP 1 geom FROM @test)
SELECT @geom = @geom.STUnion(geom) FROM @test

SELECT @geom
```

This produced the following result, which has *cracks* in it due to holes between the polygons:

[image: Combined polygons with cracks]

So I updated my query with the following change:

```
INSERT INTO @test SELECT geom.Reduce(0.001).STBuffer(100) FROM ForceBoundary
```

Which improved the result, however it's not solving the issue completely and it also damages the outer boundary accuracy.

[image: Combined polygons with less cracks]

**What is the correct way to achieve this?** From looking through a list of the STxxxx functions I couldn't see one that seemed to provide the results I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer provided by [geographika](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/186/geographika) at [GIS StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17555/calculating-the-outer-boundary-of-several-geometry-objects-in-sql-server-2008):**

It sounds like you want to remove [slivers](http://en.mimi.hu/gis/sliver.html). There is a function for this in the [SQL Server Spatial Tools](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/) project - **FilterArtifactsGeometry**.

A blog post on using the function can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edkatibah/archive/2010/12/30/new-functions-added-to-the-sql-server-spatial-tools-codeplex-project.aspx).

This has an option for filtering out small poylgons using the **ringTolerance** parameter:

*Remove all polygon rings thinner than provided tolerance (e.g. ring.STArea < ringTolerance x ring.STLength). A value of 0 will not remove any rings.*

> In practice, this allows very thin polygon rings (slivers) to be
>   detected and removed while leaving more typically shaped polygon rings
>   alone.  The presumption is, of course, that slivers are undesirable
>   but non-sliver rings are desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [geom].STExteriorRing() command?

Comment: Good suggestion - however in my case it doesn't appear to be returning anything. `SELECT @geom` returns the merged polygon as seen above. `SELECT @geom.STExteriorRing()` doesn't return anything. Appending it with `.STAsText()` returns null.